# .net application build error icon.png doesn’t exist in the package

Tags: .net, nuget

I need help with an issue I am facing in building my application. I get this error

```
NU5046 - the icon file ‘icon.png’ doesn’t exist in the package.
```

The file it points to is Nuget.build.tasks.pack.targets

I am clueless how to go from there.

Answer (score 8):

Look at you project file.

For the line:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="images\icon.png" Pack="true" PackagePath=""/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Make sure that says **Include** mine had **Update**

Comment: TWO DAYS man, it took me TWO DAYS to find this problem. I was ready to break some stuff. Thank you!

Comment: If only there was a UI or something that would maintain that project file without having to manually update it. It could be called something simple, like Visual Studio, or something. IDK, I'm just spit-balling ways to make our jobs simpler, rather than harder.